# React-Native init stuck when installing required cocoapods

Tags: react-native

I am trying to create a new project by using
`react-native init <projectName>`

But it's been stuck at this for 10min:

> info Installing required CocoaPods dependencies

Before creating my project, I installed cocoapods using

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

Why is it getting stuck?

Comment: turns out, I just had to wait longer.

Comment: Hi How long did you have to wait?  I'm facing the same situation.  Did you find a way to make it faster?

Comment: @preston took a nap, woke up & it was all good lol.

Answer (score -2):

This command will get stuck if your internet connection is unstable. Make sure you have stable wifi when you create a react native project.